# Почему использование цикла for в шейдере может сбоить?

Tags: opengl, glsl

Имею примерно вот такой шейдер для расчета отражений (все лишнее убрал):

```
#define LOOPS 64

float MyFunction(float uv) {

  float coef, testDepth, actualDepth;

  for (int i = 0; i < LOOPS; i++) {

  //float i = 0.0;
  //while (i < LOOPS) {
  //  i += 1.0;

    coef = i / (LOOPS - 1.0);

    testDepth = .. * testure(texDepth, uv).x * coef;
    actualDepth = .. * uv * coef;

    // If it hit something, then return the UV position
    if (testDepth < actualDepth) {
      depth = actualDepth - testDepth;

      break;
    }
  };

  return depth * coef;
}

void main() {
  glFragColor = vec4(vec3(MyFunction(UV)), 1.0);
}
```

По какой-то причине, GLSL решает пропустить цикл на некоторых фрагментах (черная рябь - там где `MyFunction` вернула 0), и это зависит от положения камеры (повернул - рябь сместилась, стала больше или меньше):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В теле шейдера цикл с точно заданным максимальным числом проходов (`LOOPS = 64`. Предсказать ранний выход на этапе компиляции невозможно, т.к. он зависит от данных в текстуре. Все текстуры валидные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замена `for` на `while` решила проблему:

```
  int i;
  while (i < LOOPS) {
    i++;
```

Аналогично, проблему решала фейковая добавка проверки `i` перед `break`:

```
if (testDepth < actualDepth && i > 0) {
```

Аналогично, проблему решал отказ от обращения к `i` внутри цикла:

```
  coef += 1 / (LOOPS - 1.0);
```

---

Как показала дальнейшая отладка, обращение к итератору (`i`) в цикле плохая идея. Судя по всему, разворачивание цикла при компиляции в сочетании с `break` дает нестабильные результаты.